# Fastest way to alias a function name

Tags: c++, c++11

So I'm wrapping GL Mathematics library (GLM) to replace my game engine's current vector mathematics system. I would like to keep all the naming conventions I've used so far.

For renaming classes, this is easy:

```cpp
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
namespace BromineEngine {
    typedef glm::vec4 Vec4f;
    ...
}
```

However, function are more complicated. I need to make sure the function is still in the `BromineEngine` namespace.

I thought about doing a macro inside the namespace, but afaik macros don't respect namespaces. I could also just make templated functions that forward the arguments, but this seems slow.

Any help?

Comment: Will the functions in `BromineEngine` have the exact same name or will they be capitalized as well?

Comment: These functions might be named differently. For example, `glm::to_string(...)` needs to be `BromineEngine::matrixToString(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inline functions to get what you want. For example, with a function with signature `bool(int, int)`

```cpp
inline bool rename_f(int i, int j) {
    return glm::f(i, j);
}
```

The compiler will optimize (it won't necessarily optimize any inlined functions, but for simple ones like that, it is almost guaranteed) the code and replace your function call with its body everywhere in your code.

Comment: Gorgeous, thank you! I didn't even consider using the compiler to optimize that out for me!

Comment: No problem. Also, consider using `using` instead of `typedef`, even if both notations work, `using my_int = int;` is more verbose and considered better practice for modern codebases. The reason you see `typedef` so much in libraries is for older compiler compatibility and also to have a single way to do things. 10 years old libraries cannot use two different notations, so they stick to the old one.

Comment: Ha! I'll have to go through my whole codebase and replace all the typedefs too then :)